# Javers : @annotation(org.javers.spring.annotation.JaversAuditable) not working in some project

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, javers

I have two projects, one is a real project and the second one is a demo project to try the Javers Framework with similar setting and similar environment. In the demo project, Javers audit trail is running well, but after I implementing it in the real project the Javers is not working.

I have investigated the process for several days and found this assumption 
"Javers in the real project cannot detect the pointcut (more precisely cannot detect the annotation)" :

`@AfterReturning("@annotation(org.javers.spring.annotation.JaversAuditable)")` (in JaversAuditableAspect)

Because when I create a simple aspect with the same pointcut :

```
@AfterReturning("execution(* com.xxx.StatusRepository.*(..))")
```

the aspect is execute, and when I try to hit @annotation(org.javers.spring.annotation.JaversAuditable) with another pointcut (@Before, @After, @AfterThrowing, and @Around) no one pointcut is hit.

Is there any other clue or option so I can try it?

Here is my xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    ">

    <tx:annotation-driven/>

    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/spring/mbp-infra.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/spring/mbp-util.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath*:META-INF/spring/**/*-codelist.xml" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.nttdata.mbp.domain" />

    <!-- AOP. -->
    <bean id="resultMessagesLoggingInterceptor"
        class="org.terasoluna.gfw.common.exception.ResultMessagesLoggingInterceptor">
          <property name="exceptionLogger" ref="exceptionLogger" />
    </bean>
    <aop:config proxy-target-class="true">
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="resultMessagesLoggingInterceptor"
                     pointcut="@within(org.springframework.stereotype.Service)" />
    </aop:config>

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>

    <!-- check that the aop is running -->
    <bean id = "myAspect" class = "com.nttdata.mbp.domain.util.AOPTest" />

</beans>
```

and here is my dependencies :

```
<!-- == Javers == -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.javers</groupId>
    <artifactId>javers-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.javers</groupId>
    <artifactId>javers-spring</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.javers</groupId>
    <artifactId>javers-persistence-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.3</version>    
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.javers</groupId>
    <artifactId>javers-persistence-sql</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.polyjdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>polyjdbc</artifactId>
    <version>0.6.4</version>
</dependency>
<!-- == End Javers == -->
```

**=== Update ===**

And here is my configuration for javers bean

```
@Configuration
public class AuditContext {

    @Bean
    public Javers javers() {
        JaversRepository javersRepository = SqlRepositoryBuilder
                                            .sqlRepository()
                                            .withConnectionProvider(getConnectionProvider())
                                            .withDialect(DialectName.MYSQL).build();
        return JaversBuilder.javers()
                .registerJaversRepository(javersRepository)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ConnectionProvider getConnectionProvider() {
        return new AuditConnectionProvider();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthorProvider getAuthorProvider() {
        return new SpringSecurityAuthorProvider();
    }

    @Bean
    public CommitPropertiesProvider getCommitPropertiesProvider() {
        return new CommitPropertiesProvider() {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> provide() {
                return ImmutableMap.of("key", "ok");
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public JaversAuditableAspect javersAuditableAspect() {
        return new JaversAuditableAspect(javers(),getAuthorProvider(),getCommitPropertiesProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public JaversSpringDataAuditableRepositoryAspect javersSpringDataAuditableAspect() {
        return new JaversSpringDataAuditableRepositoryAspect(javers(),getAuthorProvider(),getCommitPropertiesProvider());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As described in https://javers.org/documentation/spring-integration/
all you have to do is to enable the JaVers' aspect by declaring this bean:

```
@Bean
public JaversAuditableAspect javersAuditableAspect() {
    return new JaversAuditableAspect(javers(), authorProvider(), commitPropertiesProvider());
}
```

and enable @AspectJ support.

Full example of Spring config is available here https://javers.org/documentation/spring-integration/#spring-jpa-example
(we don't have examples in xml, I suggest updating to Java Config)

Comment: I'm sorry I don't mention it, I have updated my post with the configuration class, I also have checked the annotation `System.out.println(target.getClass().getMethod("insert", Case.class).isAnnotationPresent(JaversAuditable.class));` and result is true, but it still not working, I don't have any idea anymore.

Comment: After several days me and my friend looking for this issue, this morning he came to the office and finally found the cause. That's because someone in our team changes the component scan in spring-mvc.xml file from `<context:component-scan base-package="com.nttdata.explore.app" />` to `<context:component-scan base-package="com.nttdata.explore" />`, just losing the ".app" word. We do not pay attention to this file because everything is ok and we do not have ".app" package either. Until this simple different causing issue to @annotation pointcut (thanks to Javers, we get a new lesson from it).